# overhead of including css in head of html page rather than separate file

Tags: javascript, html, css

UPDATE: In the end this has become a non-issue. we created  proxy that serves the theme css files from the blob through the same domain as the js files.

I am developing a themeswitcher module that  uses the document.stylesheets object to get information about css rules in certain stylesheets.

the site is hosted on azure, and the css files are stored on the blob.

this makes it impossible to access to stylesheets due to lack of support for Cross-origin resource sharing in the blob.

a workaround is to inject the entire css file/s into the head section of the html page.

would this significantly affect performance by bloating the page?

EDIT:

As mentioned int he comments below, there are of course 2 factors:   the first is caching of external css files, which leads to faster re-load times.
the second is number of http requests- which become less if the css is in the page: although if the files are already cached- no request is made for them on re-load anyways.

I am trying to understand if aside from these factors, does making the html page much bigger, by adding about 3-5 style tags each with  100- 300  css rules,  in the header section, cause scripts to run slower on the page because the html string itself is much longer?

Comment: one man's "impossible" is another man's "you're doing it wrong". I don't see how same-origin policy would prevent you from doing anything - it certainly doesn't prevent cdns from serving css files.

Comment: AD7six: are you able to access the stylesheets in the document.stylesheets object, of a css file that is served from a CDN with no CORS support?   The CDN of course serves the file and it affects the style of the page. but javascript is denied access to read the innards of the css rules in the file.

Answer (score 2):

If it is in the page, it will take **longer** to load due to the css *not* already being in the browser's cache on second load.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on different factors. For example - how big is your css and where are your users go to your site from. If your target audience are - mobile users, every extra kb of data may be significantly affect performance and cost you negative user experience. On the other hand each external stylesheet is an http request which may affect performance even more. So it depends on your particular case